# Problems to access to other module with the same parent name in Python

Tags: python, import, package

In my company we decided to structure own python modules using this convention:

```
dsc.<package_name>
```

It works without any problem when two modules is used in other project that doesn't follow this convention. However, when in a develop environment I try to develop a new module "dsc.new_module" that references to other, for example, "dsc.other_module", the import raises a not module found exception. Is there any way to solve this?

If I package the module and install, everything is correct but not when I'm developing the module that is not able to find it. The only way I overcome this problem is doing that:

```py
try:
    from dsc.other_module import send_message
except ImportError:
    def dummy(a, b):
        pass
    send_message = dummy
```

Beacause the function is not essential.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is install your packages in development mode. `pip install -e . (from the parent folder)` After this the imports should work as you envision them, so the same as other packages that use them.

Development mode is not required, but it adds the benefit of implementing changes made to your code immediately.

Comment: Thank you very much.